# How to solve a 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 error?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a React JS site that worked fine. Lastly I have changed my root password of my DigitalOcean Droplet. After changing the root password, the site showed an Error Message "502 Bad Getway". How to resolve it?

Error Log:
1553 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 203.192.236.215, server: elisonshop.net, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:7777/index.html", host: "www.elisonshop.net"

Comment: Are you passing proxy to your react site from nginx? what does your `nginx.conf` look like?

Comment: user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
 worker_connections 768;
 # multi_accept on;
}

http {

 ##
 # Basic Settings
 ##

Comment: Did you try googling anything? I found https://bobcares.com/blog/502-bad-gateway-nginx-digitalocean/ for example.

Comment: sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout 65;
 types_hash_max_size 2048;
 # server_tokens off;

 # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
 # server_name_in_redirect off;

Comment: @HRMehbubtechMRahman Please [edit] your question to include the requested info so that you can format it properly

Comment: include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;

 ##
 # SSL Settings
 ##

 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 ##
 # Logging Settings
 ##

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

Comment: ##
 # Gzip Settings
 ##

 gzip on;

 # gzip_vary on;
 # gzip_proxied any;
 # gzip_comp_level 6;
 # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
 # gzip_http_version 1.1;
 # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

 ##
 # Virtual Host Configs
 ##

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

Comment: #mail {
# # See sample authentication script at:
# # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
# # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
# # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
# # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:110;
#  protocol   pop3;
#  proxy      on;
# }
# 
# server {
#  listen     localhost:143;
#  protocol   imap;
#  proxy      on;
# }
#}

Comment: please check my config file that i have mentioned in the comment

Comment: is there any way to resolve it ......elisonshop.net is my application

Comment: I have tried all commands provided in digital ocean help site on behalf of NGINX. but nothing is working

Comment: site was running smoothly be fore changing root password. After changed the password site going down.

Comment: 1553 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 203.192.236.215, server: elisonshop.net, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:7777/index.html", host: "www.elisonshop.net"

Comment: first of all, remove all your private information including  ip-adresses from log. Please use the "edit" function of stackoverflow to include all of logs/codes now. If you want help, you need to make it easier for us to understand your problem. Logs say your upstream of localhost at port 7777 is refusing connections. Make sure your React app is running first.

Comment: Can I change the port 7777 to 8080?